# Hello! I have a question about a jQuery if statement. The if statement always runs even after the condition becomes false. Any thoughts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

The code seems to run the if statement even after the condition of started is set to true.

I have tried doing this as well but it still has the same bug. 
if (started === false && started !== true)

```
if (started == false){ /*this always runs even after started is 
                           set to true??? */

      //when any key pressed, start the game // exit if statement?
    $(document).on("keypress",function(event){
      console.log(started + "started inside keydown function");
      startGame();    // <-- runs another function that also sets 
                         //started to true
      started = true;
    });

    $("body").on("click",function(){
      console.log(started + "inside click function");
      checkClicks++;
      if(checkClicks > 2){
        $("h1").text("Press any KEY first to start the game!");
      }
    });
  }
```

The solution below for those having similar issues. Turns out callBacks are always called no matter what. Best to put statements inside them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var started = false;
  var checkClicks = 0;
  /*change h1 to notify player to type a key first*/



  //when any key pressed, start the game // exit if statement?
  $(document).on("keypress",function(){
    if (started == false) {
      //console.log(started + "started inside keydown function");
      startGame();
      started = true;

    }
  }
);

$("body").on("click",function(){
  if(started == false){
    //console.log(started + "inside click function");
    checkClicks++;
    if(checkClicks > 2){
      $("h1").text("Press any KEY first to start the game!");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: the callback `$(document).on("keypress",function(event){` is called on `keypress` ... every keypress, it's a callback setup to be called on keypress, and it doesn't care about the if condtion outside of the callback, the callback doesn't know about the if statement ... put the if statement inside the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the callback `$(document).on("keypress",function(event){` is called on `keypress` ... every keypress, it's a callback setup to be called on keypress, and it doesn't care about the if condtion outside of the callback, the callback doesn't know about the if statement ... put the if statement inside the callback

```
$(document).on("keypress",function(event){
  if (started == false) {
    console.log(started + "started inside keydown function");
    startGame();
    started = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks! didn't know callbacks always ran. works as intended now